# Can I replace my Tkinter UI with a Javascript UI?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I'd like to write a Javascript UI to download my Goodreads' private group's Bookshelf. I have a working Python program with a `tkinter` interface right now.

**OLD QUESTION:** My primary question is "Is this possible?" as in "Can my Python program be completely written in Javascript?". Answer: NO!! Javascript can't work around CORS issues. See the Javascript example below.

**REVISED QUESTIONS:** Can I replace my Tkinter UI with a Javascript UI in my existing Python program? Should I be writing a Javascript programs that calls Python code or writing a Python program that calls a Javascript script? The parts I need Python for are for the `request` and for using Pandas to format and parse the data. I'd like my Javascript UI to use the JSON file I have for Shelf info (`name`, `url`, `save_path`, `output_path`, `last_download_timestamp`, etc)

I think my question is a duplicate of: [How do I call a python script when clicking a button (using pyscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321468/how-do-i-call-a-python-script-when-clicking-a-button-using-pyscript) and an outside source: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/pyscript-javascript-and-python-interoperability/

Here are some other similar threads I found. There's a lot of info but a much of it was posted many years ago:

[How do I call a python script when clicking a button (using pyscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321468/how-do-i-call-a-python-script-when-clicking-a-button-using-pyscript)

[Call Python function from JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175665/9915864
  *Is this still relevant today?*
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962931/9915864
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125467/9915864

[How do I call a Javascript function from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284765/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-python)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965237/9915864
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757842/9915864

```py
import requests

### This is the relevant python call. 
### It functions as long as I'm logged in through a browser.
class GR_access:
    ...
    # security values replace with '...'
    cookies = {
        'ccsid': '...',
        'locale': 'en',
        '_session_id2': '...',
        'blocking_sign_in_interstitial': 'true',
        'u': '...',
        'p': '...',
        'likely_has_account': 'true',
        }

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'If-None-Match': '...',
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=GR_access.headers, cookies=GR_access.cookies)
```

What I've tried:

Here's the JavaScript page I'm working with right now with same cookies (in correct format) & headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fetch Page with Custom Headers and Cookie</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fetch Page with Custom Headers and Cookie</h1>

    <div id="response"></div>

    <script>
        // stripped group
        const url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/'; 
        // replaced security values with '...'
        const headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'If-None-Match': '...',
}

// replaced security values with '...'
        const cookie = "ccsid='...';'locale'='en';'_session_id2'= '...';'blocking_sign_in_interstitial'='true';'u'='...';'p'='...';'likely_has_account'= 'true'"

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers(headers),
            credentials: 'include', // Sending cookies
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.text(); // Use response.json() if expecting JSON
                }
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById('response').innerText = data; // Display response on the HTML page
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran the script from the same browser I'm logged into on my GR account. I also tried replacing the older `const cookie` value with the `cookie` value of the current page I'm logged in to. The web browser's Web Developer Tools > Console output gives me the following errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]https://www.goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/...[/url]. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]https://www.goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/...[/url]. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

The current headers & cookies look nothing like the old ones, so obviously things have changed. I'm just not sure if I'm doing something technically wrong or if there's no functional solution.

Comment: *"CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing"* - If the remote server does not explicitly allow cross-origin requests then your browser will disallow the request.  Before spending a lot of time debugging, you'll first want to confirm with that service if they allow CORS at all.

Comment: If you're new to CORS I highly suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/3982562). The examples make it really easy to understand.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate but not of the question provided by the mods. This question is probably closer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900950/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-scripts-client-side-in-the-browser-using-a-front-en